# Create nuget package from old-style framework project referencing netstandard project

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget, .net-standard

I have a solution containing:

- an old-style .Net Framework 4.6 project (i.e. it does not use the newer project sdk stuff, it has a packages.config file and a nuspec file)
- a netstandard project

The framework project references the netstandard project via a project reference.

I'm trying to find a way of packaging the framework project, taking into account the dependency on the netstandard project (such that the netstandard project appears as a dependency of the framework project, rather than being bundled in it).

I've tried:

- `nuget pack -IncludeReferencedProjects`

  - this fails with "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'NuGet.Frameworks.NuGet.Frameworks1070507.NuGetFramework'" because of the netstandard project (a known issue, e.g. https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4808)
- Importing the nuget pack target in the framework csproj (`<Import Project="$(MSBuildSDKsPath)\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\build\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets" />`), then `dotnet pack` or `msbuild /t:pack`

  - this fails with errors about a missing project.assets.json file (which I don't think is a thing for projects using packages.config?)
  - if I further specify `/p:NuspecFile=[path to nuspec]`, this gets me further and things seem to work, *but* the netstandard project dependency gets bundled as part of the package

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you want to build multi-target NuGet package, by migrating the code from an old project ?

Well, I was doing it routinely by creating new project, setting multi-targets, drag'n'drop all items and hope that you have survivable number of unsupported assemblies.

I've wrote a guide for that (actually it is compilation of ideas from around the web) and made VS extension with multi-target project template. So, if I'm in your shoes, I would install the extension, create new "Blank multi-target project" and copied all items from the old one.

- [The imbACE BasicPack extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=imbVeles.imbACEBasicPack)
- [Tutorial on using the multi-target template: Getting started with multi-target project](http://blog.veles.rs/imbace-basicpack-getting-started-draft/)

Just in your case, you should change .net45 target to equivalent of your preference. In tutorial you'll find some tips regarding unsupported assemblies and so on. The project template it self does 80% of job for you. At least, in my case (migrating 9 libraries), once I adopted the methodology, it was piece of cake.

Comment: No, I don't want to migrate the old project. I want to add a reference from the old (framework) project to a new netstandard project

Comment: Well, I had problems with "deep" references, i.e. a my old project was referencing NuGet packages and/or dlls that are not compiled/targeted for .NET Standard 2.0 - therefore: you can't do it.

Comment: The netstandard project in this case targets 1.0 - there are no problems with references compiling and running - it's just the nuget packing that's the problem

Comment: My solution (here I em again) was to migrate (old project) to multi-target, as I couldn't find another solution, because: even if you make these assemblies working together, what is purpose having .NET Standard project that is not cross-platform?

Comment: The netstandard project is cross-platform. The framework project isn't, but depends on the netstandard project (which is independently published as a package).

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'NuGet.Frameworks.NuGet.Frameworks1070507.NuGetFramework 
but this one I'll have in my nightmare, cause I can't grasp what the hek

Comment: Could you migrate 4.6 to somewhat newer i.e. 4.6.1+ -- this sounds to me like a hell of a bug

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue by upgrading `nuget.exe` to 4.9.3 (was 4.5.1)